grpc c++ - Shared library vs static library
I tried to build grpc c++ in two ways. One with -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON and one without it.
When it is off, I get in the lib/ directory, for example:
360M libgrpc.a

(Any many other libraries)
When it is ON, I get in the lib/ directory
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Jul  8 11:32 grpc_so/lib/libgrpc.so -> libgrpc.so.41
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Jul  8 11:32 grpc_so/lib/libgrpc.so.41 -> libgrpc.so.41.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root rot  58M Jul  8 11:30 grpc_so/lib/libgrpc.so.41.0.0

(and many other .so files)
Why is such a difference in the library size? I read that static library contains its dependencies, but in fact even in the static build I do see other dependencies of grpc in the lib/ folder (example libabsl*.a files), so it is not like libgrpc.a is self contained.
All the other libraries also have a larger size in the static build. What these .a files contains that the .so files do not?
I'm trying to get a small, runtime only grpc c++ build. Not sure if I should compile it as shared library or not.

I would suggest against measuring library size outside of your application. Try building your application to let the linker drop unnecessary code. Bazel may also be helpful in pruning unnecessary code.
E.g. building greeter server with Bazel on Linux x86-64:
bazel build -c opt //examples/cpp/helloworld:greeter_server

produces a 13M executable. That may be further decreased by disabling xDS and such.
